# Detect if an element is deleted from Codemirror with backspace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codemirror

When i delete the following "*label*" as a block using the backspace key, i would like to detect this event and do an ajax call, for example.

**This part is deleted when i use backspace**

[image: textarea]

**Rendered**

[image: textarea]

The problem is: there can be lots of labels (`a` tags) in textarea with different id's, i want to detect when any block is going to be deleted, save the id and remove.

**Configuration**

I'm using a custom configuration with a custom entity called `annotation` which represents the HTML above.

```
// Create CodeMirror (with lineWrapping on).
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad-container'), {lineWrapping: true});

// Create Firepad (with rich text toolbar and shortcuts enabled).
var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, {
    richTextShortcuts: true,
    richTextToolbar: true,
    userId: userId,
    userColor: userImage,
});

//// Create FirepadUserlist (with our userId, user name and avatar to display).
var firepadUserList = FirepadUserlist.fromDiv(firepadRef.child('users'),
    document.getElementById('userlist'), userId, displayName, userImage);

firepad.registerEntity('annotation', {
    render: function (info, entityHandler) {
        var inputElement = document.createElement('a');
        if(info.id) {
            inputElement.setAttribute('id', info.id);
        }
        if(info.classList) {
            inputElement.setAttribute('class', info.classList);
        }
        if(info.color || info.cursor) {
            inputElement.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + info.color + '; cursor:' + info.cursor + ';');
        }
        inputElement.innerText = info.innerText;

        inputElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            editAnnotation(info.id, e);
            entityHandler.remove();
        });

        return inputElement;
    }.bind(this),
    fromElement: function (element) {
        var info = {};
        if(element.hasAttribute('id')) {
            info.id = element.id;
        }
        if(element.hasAttribute('class')) {
            info.classList = element.classList;
        }

        info.color = element.style["color"];
        info.cursor = element.style["cursor"];
        info.innerText = element.innerText;

        return info;
    },
    update: function (info, element, entityHandler) {
        if(info.id) {
            element.setAttribute('id', info.id);
        }
        if(info.classList) {
            element.setAttribute('class', info.classList);
        }
        if(info.color || info.cursor) {
            element.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + info.color + '; cursor:' + info.cursor + ';');
        }
        element.innerText = info.innerText;
    },
    export: function () {
        var inputElement = document.createElement('a');
        return inputElement;
    }
});
```

If you want to add this new entity just use this:

```
firepad.insertEntity('annotation', { 'id': annotationId, 'color': color, 'cursor': 'pointer', 'innerText': 'whatever you want'});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the configuration your using? I would like to assist in a solution, but I can't recreate your HTML output.

Comment: Here you go, added the configuration